# How can I increment value of json data if it meets certain conditions?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My json data is like this :

```
$json_data = '{"1": "1", "2": "1"}';
```

Note :

> 1 = star
>
> 1 = the number of users who give star 1
>
> 2 = star
>
> 1 = the number of users who give star 2

If I have variables like this :

```
$star = 1;
```

I want check variable `$star`  exist in key of `$json_data` or not

If exist, it will update to be :

```
$json_data = '{"1": "2", "2": "1"}';
```

So, if `$star` exist in key of `$json_data`, it will increment the value

I try like this :

```
<?php 
    $star = 1;
    $json_data = '{"1": "1", "2": "1"}';
    $array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
    if(array_key_exists($star, $array_data)) {
        $value = $array_data[$star];
        if ($value !== false) {
            // update here
        }
                   
    }
?>
```

I'm still confused, how to update it

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything to stay as strings inside of your JSON data I would use this code.  I cast the variable first as an int then add 1 to it.  Then I cast it as a string.

```
<?php 

$star = 1;
$json_data = '{"1": "1", "2": "1"}';
$array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
if(array_key_exists($star, $array_data)) {
    $value = $array_data[$star];
    if ($value !== false) {
        $array_data[$star] = (string)((int)$value + 1);
    }

}

echo json_encode($array_data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use isset()

```
if(isset($array_data[$star])) {
    $array_data[$star]++;
}else{
    $array_data[$star]=1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$star = 1;
$json_data = '{"1": "1", "2": "1"}';
$array_data = json_decode($json_data, true);
if(array_key_exists($star, $array_data)) {
    if (isset($array_data[$star]) AND $array_data[$star] !== false) {
        $array_data[$star] = 'change';
    }

}
$json_data = json_encode($array_data);
```

You can also learn about passing variables as references but thats not needed here